# Match query issues after upgrading ES1.7->2.4 and NEST 1.x->2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I upgraded to NEST 2.x from NEST 1.x and have been having trouble performing very basic searches.

This is my query which used to work on ES 1.7

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "customer.companyId": {
        "query": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is how I need to change it to make it work in ES 2.4.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "companyId": {
        "query": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/match-query.html

I'm not sure if it's ES or NEST that's being picky. Is this the new rule with ES 2.x that we don't include the full object path only field names and ES will figure out to what object that field name belongs?

What if 2 documents have a field with the same name - how can I narrow the search to 1 document type only?

With NEST I create the query the following way:

```
 query = new MatchQuery()
                {
                    Field = Field.Create("customer.companyId"),
                    Query = queryValue,
                    Fuzziness = Fuzziness.EditDistance(fuzziness),
                    Operator = logicalOperator
                };
```

This page shows another way to create the Field
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/match-usage.html

```
query = new MatchQuery()
            {
                Field = Field<Customer>(p => p.companyId),
                Query = queryValue,
                Fuzziness = Fuzziness.EditDistance(fuzziness),
                Operator = logicalOperator
            };
```

Unfortunately `Field<Customer>(p => p.companyId),` doesn't compile!!!

Comment: What does your mapping (in Elasticsearch and POCO) look like? Without the mapping, it's difficult to answer

Comment: `Field<Customer>(p => p.companyId)` has a static import for `Nest.Infer`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/2.x/src/Tests/QueryDsl/FullText/Match/MatchUsageTests.cs#L4

Comment: @RussCam thanks you! that import was it. It looks like an implicit in Scala.